# Trying to make a table in HTML using Flask and with data from SQL

Tags: javascript, python, html, sql, flask

I was trying to make a table in HTML using data from my database to populate the table. However, the table is showing up but there is no data present in the table. Can you guys please help?

This is my HTML Code with javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    th{ 
        color:#fff;
            }
</style>


<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr  class="bg-info">
        <th>worker_id</th>
        <th>wokrer_name</th>
        <th>worker_type</th>
        <th>regular_hours</th>
        <th>hourly_rate</th>
        <th>overtime_rate</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="myTable">
        
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var myArray = JSON.parse("{JSON_data}")
    
    buildTable(myArray)



    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].worker_id}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].worker_name}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].worker_type}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].regular_hours}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].hourly_rate}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].overtime_rate}</td>
                      </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row


        }
    }

</script>
```

This is my Python Code

```
@app.route("/view_worker")
def view_worker():
  f = open("templates/view_worker.html")
  page = f.read()
  f.close()
  cursor.execute("""
    SELECT
      *
    FROM workers
  """,
  )
  data = cursor.fetchall()
  worker_data = []
  for row in data:
    worker = {"worker_id":row[0], "worker_name":row[1], "worker_type":row[2], "regular_hours":row[3], "hourly_rate":row[4], "overtime_rate":row[5]}
    worker_data.append(worker)
  worker_data = json.dumps(worker_data)
  page = page.replace("{JSON_data}", worker_data)
  return page
```

I am pretty new to python and html and I know nothing about javascript. I just saw a youtube tutorial on javascript and tried to reverse engineer his code to suit my needs.

I wanted tried to make a table which will show data in my database and dynamically become larger/smaller with the amount of data in the database. But sadly, it is not working and I have no clue on how to solve this.

If it helps, in the youtube tutorial, the array used was:

```
[
        {'name':'Michael', 'age':'30', 'birthdate':'11/10/1989'},
        {'name':'Mila', 'age':'32', 'birthdate':'10/1/1989'},
        {'name':'Paul', 'age':'29', 'birthdate':'10/14/1990'},
        {'name':'Dennis', 'age':'25', 'birthdate':'11/29/1993'},
        {'name':'Tim', 'age':'27', 'birthdate':'3/12/1991'},
        {'name':'Erik', 'age':'24', 'birthdate':'10/31/1995'},
    ]
```

And this was added directly in the html code rather than putting it in. I think this may be the mistake in my code as the data may not be in the correct format

Comment: It may be helpful to read the documentation under ["Rendering Templates"](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates). To pass data between Jinja (Flask's template engine) and JavaScript, the Jinja [filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#filters) [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson) is a solution.

Comment: To familiarize yourself with Flask, I also recommend this tutorial. ["The Flask Mega Tutorial" by Miguel Grinberg](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

Answer (score 1):

I think the missing concept here is Jinja templates.

Your approach is:

1. Read your custom "template" file
2. Serialize the worker data to JSON
3. Use plain string manipulation to inject the JSON into a string literal in a `<script>` tag within the template
4. Send the prepared template string to the client
5. Run JS client-side to parse the JSON and inject it into the document

A simpler approach would be using the built-in Jinja templating engine to avoid all of the above steps. No need to read files, manipulate strings, serialize and deserialize JSON, or use any JS. Instead, pass your data directly into `render_template` and use a Jinja loop to generate the HTML on the server and send it to the client fully-formed.

Here's an example.

app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template  # 2.2.3


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.get("/workers")
def view_workers():
    # mock data; assume your db is returning the data OK
    workers = [
        {"name": "Michael", "age": "30", "birthdate": "11/10/1989"},
        {"name": "Mila", "age": "32", "birthdate": "10/1/1989"},
        {"name": "Paul", "age": "29", "birthdate": "10/14/1990"},
        {"name": "Dennis", "age": "25", "birthdate": "11/29/1993"},
        {"name": "Tim", "age": "27", "birthdate": "3/12/1991"},
        {"name": "Erik", "age": "24", "birthdate": "10/31/1995"},
    ]
    return render_template("view_workers.html", workers=workers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

templates/view_workers.html:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr class="bg-info">
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
    <th>birthdate</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    {% for worker in workers %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ worker["name"] }}</td>
      <td>{{ worker["age"] }}</td>
      <td>{{ worker["birthdate"] }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Run with `flask run --debug` then navigate to `localhost:5000/workers` to see your workers rendered.

Generally, use JS only if you need real-time behavior that doesn't involve a page load (for example, autocomplete search or input validation as a user types, modal pop-ups, etc) or you're following a single page application architecture where HTML is built client-side after the page loads. Neither appear to apply here.

Note also that you have different columns in the db and sample data. I used the sample data, so you may need to adjust the above code to match your actual columns.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for your help. However, when I am doing cursor.fetchall() I am recieving the values in the form - `[(123, 'Sanjan Krishna', 'assembly line worker', 40, 12.0, 14.0)].` I am not getting the values as a dictionary and that is why I was converting it to a dictionary. Am I doing something wrong?

I am using MSSQL instead of MySQL so could that be the issue?

Please ignore my previous comment, I put it by mistake

Comment: That's a minor change. Use `worker[1]` instead of `worker["name"]`, `worker[3]` instead of `worker["age"]`. Add more columns and headers if you need. You can delete comments you didn't mean to add.

Comment: Oh, ya I completely forgot about that. Thank you very much for your help :)